# R CMD check throwing oversize subdirectory note for folder not in source folder and Non-ASCII error

Tags: r, package

I have been trying to clean up notes and warnings from a package I am building.

I have been using

```
R CMD build --resave-data package
```

and

```
R CMD check package.tar.gz
```

My issue is that I get the following NOTE and Warning with absolutely no idea where they come from after running `R CMD check`.

#### NOTE

[image]

The problem is that there is no `help` subdirectory in my package folder. I can find one in the `package.RCheck` folder though. Even after removing that folder, it still throws that note.

EDIT: RESOLVED - Size issue was related to a sub-folder in the man directory containing a high resolution image. Fixed by reducing the size of the image.

#### Warning

[image]

The `Seurat` package is correctly installed as the vignettes build without an issue. It is also under depends in the DESCRIPTION file and under `import` in the NAMESPACE. I am not sure I understand why this error is being thrown during the non-ASCII character check. I have ensured that I am using UTF-8 encoding.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and ways to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is your package currently on github somewhere so we can run the code ourselves to debug the issue? The help folder should be where all your documentation is compiled to when you build your package. Are you using `roxygen2` to make your documentation or are you building your own .rd files yourself? Do you have examples in your documentation that produce a lot of output?

Comment: It is available here: https://github.com/patrickCNMartin/Vesalius

I used `roxygen2` for the manual pages yes. As the examples are quite computationally  intensive, I used `\dontrun`

But I think I have at least solved the size issue. There was a figure folder in the man directory containing a high resolution image used in the README. 

I am currently testing R CMD build and check without the high res image before making a new push.

Comment: The image was indeed the issue for the size. I have added a reduced size image and now I don't get that NOTE anymore. 

The non-ASCII warning is still there though. 

Thank you for looking into this!